# Limiting probability of classifying correctly with the k-NN algorithm as the number of data points increases.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, machine-learning

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be random variables that are uniformly distributed on [0,2]. If $x_i \leq 1$, we'll classify it as green ($y_i=0$), and if $x_i > 1$, we'll classify it as red ($y_i=1$). We want to classify the point $x=1.1$ with the $k$-NN algorithm where $k=1$ and data points $(x_1,y_1),\ldots,(x_n,y_n)$.

**Prove that the probability of classifying $x=1.1$ correctly as red converges to 1 as n goes to infinity.**

Hint: *Do not try to calculate the probabilities.*

---

I haven't been able to solve the above problem. Can you solve it? I've tried to calculate the probabilities even though the hint suggests not to do this. I've also tried using inequalities such as Markov's.

Comment: Observe that if any $x_i$ lies in $(1, 1.1]$ (so that $y_i = 1$), then the classifer will classify $x = 1.1$ correctly.

Comment: Should I compute the probability that at least one $x_i$ lies in (1,1.1] using the complement rule?

Comment: You could, and this would solve the problem.  However, since you are given a hint to not calculate probabilities, perhaps there is a more general theorem you can use, so you might want to give us more context about your question to see if there is an "intended" solution.  Btw, I realized that it suffices for any $x_i$ to lie in the interval $(1, 1.2)$ in order to correctly classify $x = 1.1$, so this is an easy way to get a sharper estimate of the probability of a correct classification.

Comment: Thank you. I think I got it now. I might add a solution soon. :-)